# What should I do if a new iOS version introduces possible class collisions (Apple classes with the same prefix as mine)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm dealing with this problem in iOS 8.3, where a new set of classes have been introduced that could potentially conflict with my classes because they use the same prefix. Should I worry? Should I use prefixes at all, or should only frameworks/libraries use them? Can I refactor all class names at once if needed?

Comment: before i vote to close, here is my opinion :) : **1)** prefer prefixing to guard against the practical joke departments (in my case Apple and cocos2d) **2)** If you chose to refactor , use an IDE (like AppCode), not a toy.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Thanks for the reply. I disagree with your vote - the primary question "What should I do if a new iOS version introduces possible class collisions?" is not opinion-based, if there are conflicts in new iOS versions, then there must be a solution, and a common one. This can't be the first time this has happened.

Comment: not my close vote, when i came to edit out my snarky, the grace period was expired. Nonetheless, i feel everyone will have their preferred way to deal with this situation. After being 'yanked' into a forklift refactoring project a couple of times, i chose to prefix my 'app' stuff to protect my codebase.

Answer (score 1):

Just go with the safer option of prefixing your classes. This will then mean you never need to worry about this problem again.

Comment: I am prefixing my classes. So I guess you are suggesting re-prefexing them. Is there an easy way to do this? Xcode doesn't seem to provide one.

Comment: Unless you've been using NS as your prefix - I don't see the need to "re-prefix" them ?

Comment: My current prefix is being used by a new set of classes Apple introduced - that's why I'm asking this question

Comment: That wasn't clear. Then you need to re-prefix them. There isn't a one click solution to this either. Out of curiosity - what are you prefixing them with currently?

Answer (score 0):

Always prefix your class name with your company/app name whenever you create the class. Personally I prefer 3 characters instead of 2 characters, since Apple has the right to prefix their class name with 2 letters.

For example, if you have a class named CoreData and your company name is Foo Bar,  your app is called Rabbit, name the class “FBRCoreData” instead of “CoreData”.

I suppose your best practise would be renaming your class names (all of them if possible ) with the prefix. Otherwise it may bite you again later.

Comment: I am prefixing my classes. So I guess you are suggesting re-prefexing them. Is there an easy way to do this? Xcode doesn't seem to provide one.

Comment: @mattsven Unfortunately I do not recall there is a "one click" solution in Xcode to re-prefix your class names.